# Can somebody tell me why this ring homomorphism is invalid?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In my algebra class I'm doing an assignment related to IBN (invariant basis number). I have shown that given a ring homomorphism $\varphi:R\to S$, if $R$ does not have IBN then $S$ does not have IBN. However, it seems to me that for any ring I could "mod out" by the commutator subring $C$, i.e. define a ring homomorphism $\varphi:R\to R/C$ by $\varphi(r)=r+C$. This is a homomorphism, and $R/C$ is a commutative ring and therefore must have IBN (we proved this, but it's a well known fact as well). Shouldn't this imply $R$ has IBN?

edit: I should add I know next to nothing about commutator subrings aside from the definition. I am only really familiar with commutator subgroups. These might not even be ideals for all I know, although I would think they are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to mod out by the two-sided ideal (not subring) generated by all commutators to get a ring. This is frequently the unit ideal, so $S$ frequently ends up being the zero ring (for example when $R = M_n(k)$ is a matrix algebra, $n \ge 2$). In other words, many noncommutative rings do not admit nonzero maps into commutative rings.

The zero ring does not have IBN; the correct statement for commutative rings is that every *nonzero* commutative ring has IBN (since, assuming choice, it's precisely the nonzero commutative rings that admit maps into fields).